# PHP: How can be protected variable accessed from child Class if he have different value?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

How can a protected variable be accessed from a child Class if it has a different value?

**Example to wrong access**: parent::$_my gives error

```
class Father{
  protected $_my=array('a','b');
}

class Child{
   protected $_my=array('c','d');
  function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   $this->_my=array_merge(parent::$_my,$this->_my);
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: If you want the class to inherit from another, you must use the `extends` keyword - like `Class Child extends Father`

Comment: Protected variables can be accessed by children, that's how it works? `$_my` in `Child` will overwrite the values set in `Father`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->_my` will be inherited from the parent when you instantiate a subclass, so you simply need to use:

```
$this->_my = array_merge($this->_my, array('c','d'));
```

Comment: Thanks,It what i write in my application know , but how can i call with parent?

Comment: As Chris mentioned, `$_my` is inherited from the parent, to the child. Its all the same and there is no "parent property". You access it like any other property via `$this->_my`.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with you design. You have already declared a variable that can be accessed by child inside parent.

Try adding values to already existing variable, rather than redefining it.